# Listing and comparing in view value from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created an Entity Framework project in ASP.NET MVC and I created a submit form to doing a login data compare that ver the data from textfields and set it into two tempData var that redirect to another Pages with name auth this page does a verification if the values of the textfield is equal the value from controller, I copy the default ASP.NET MVC index enumerable and I paste it in the new page `simple.cs` file and I add into foreach default but I have a error how I can do it without error and sabe the variable value in a class forever ?

Comment: Will be nice to post some code if you want answers !

Comment: Adding to @DarkkL comment, it would be nice to have some code. Take a look at the link for more guidance https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Solved i only just adding in the home controller the fallowing code from another viewmodel controller

```
private readonly Contexto _context;
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;


        public HomeController(Contexto context, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
        }
```

//   and in the page i use the async it catch the context and i passing que values from db to the view:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Autenticar()
        {
            //HomeController();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                return View(await _context.Cadastro.ToListAsync());
            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View();
        }
```